# Error updating nodejs using npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, version, vmware

I read many posts here teaching how to update nodejs by using npm. I followed all the proposed steps by I keep getting the same error:

```
administrator@Ubuntu-CPDiX-Test-Machine:~$ npm install -g npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: npm
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/administrator/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! cwd /home/administrator
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: npm

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! cwd /home/administrator
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/administrator/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I get this error when I work in a virtual machine: a VMWare Ubuntu 12.04.5. Would you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From inside that virtual machine, can you use wget to connect to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm ?  If not, you have a networking problem with your virtual machine.

Comment: You should seriously consider upgrading your version of node first since node v0.6 is ancient. v0.10 is the latest stable branch and contains the latest security fixes in OpenSSL too. You cannot upgrade node via npm (which is only for third party node modules).

Answer (score 0):

Read the error:

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

Try:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

And as @mscdex said, you have to upgrade you node version. it is really old.